# System of three non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been interested in a problem that involves a fairly simple looking set of differential equations:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=yz\;\;\;\frac{dy}{dt}=xz\;\;\;\frac{dz}{dt}=xy
$$

From this it follows that $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y}{x}$, $\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{z}{y}$, etc.

Besides the trivial solutions of $x=0, y=0, z=0$, and where one of $x, y$ or $z$ equals some constant $k$ and the rest equal 0, I'm not sure how to continue with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int x\text dx=\int y\text dy$ and therefore $y^2=x^2+b$ and, similarly, $z^2=x^2+c$, for constants $b$ and $c$.

That means that $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+b}\sqrt{x^2+c}}\text dx=\int \text dt.$$

You may be surprised to learn that this integral does **not** have an elementary solution.

You could however find various solutions to your system of differential equations by looking at special cases such as $b=c,b=0, ...$

For example with $b=c=0$ we have $$\int \frac{1}{x^2}\text dx=\int \text dt.$$
Then one solution is $x=y=z=-\frac{1}{t+a}$ and you might like to check this works.

Hope you can find some other interesting solutions.